# Recommended couchdb server setup?

Tags: couchdb, vps

As we’re starting our new project, we are being challenged to choose our cloud VPS provider. And we’re faced with many options, some affordable some not, some of them offer more vCPUs some offer more ram, SSD ... etc.

Unfortunately, we do not have any experience with a production level couchdb server and we don’t know on what server spec to focus.

Our couchdb server will be accessed by 300 clients at the same time maximum. Not a big number, but most of them will be replicating databases to their devices.

Would such a setup benefit with more RAM? CPU cores? Or faster SSDs?

Would a vertical scaling benefit us more than horizontal scaling?

Also some providers have their SSDs network-attached, how much would that negatively affect the latency? Noticeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: full disclosure, I work for Cloudant so my answer may or may not be applicable. I can't speak with authority on CouchDB setup, but can share some of Cloudant's experiences on the topic. Our needs are different.

TL;DR -- if I had to choose *one* of more RAM, more cores or faster SSDs, I'd choose more RAM, but all matters.

Cloudant's DB nodes all have large amounts of RAM as this gives the Erlang VM room to breathe once the number of requests each node needs to handle grow. In terms of SSDs, a well-configured CouchDB system should be able to saturate its host's disk IO, and for this reason we run Cloudant on bare-metal, with local disks. Networked storage directly impacts latency.

The number of cores has an effect on sharding patterns in a clustered setup, and ultimately throughput.

However, your numbers are fairly modest. Couch is built to be able to scale horizontally. My suggestion would be to spec your nodes with as much RAM as you can afford, avoid network-attached storage and scale by putting more nodes in.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question cannot be answered in a general way, for too many factors will influence the performance of your final infrastructure. Just to give you some aspects in example:

- A lot of RAM: many requests (especially with large payload) could be handled efficiently
- Many CPU cores: Fast response time for multiple requests at the same time
- SSD's: Fast read / write operations for static data

It really depends on your application what the CouchDB server should actually do and how these operations could be improved with appropriate hardware.